# Why does creating a Font based on a nonexistent FontFamily work?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+

I am drawing some text with Gdi+ and I'm trying to make sure the Font I create actually exists. I noticed that it was working no matter what font I specified. I have the following code:

```
Font font(TEXT("SomeGibberishFOEIHSFUE"), 12, 0, UnitPoint);

if (!font.IsAvailable())
    exit(0);

// draw text
```

I have no font installed on my system called `SomeGibberishFOEIHSFUE`, but `IsAvailable` returns `TRUE` and the program runs and draws the text with a font that looks like Arial instead of exiting. Why is this?

If I am using `IsAvailable` wrong, what function should I use to tell whether the creation of a Font succeeded or not? I have also tried `GetLastStatus` which returns `Ok`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the Windows font mapper at work, it will always find a substitute font if it cannot supply the requested one.  Falling back to the default GUI font if necessary.  You could use the FontFamily class instead.  The .NET version of it (looks like you're using it) will throw an ArgumentException when you use its constructor and pass a non-existing font.  The native GDI+ version of it has an [IsAvailable() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536180%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Yes, kinda screwy behavior but that's not unusual in GDI+.

Comment: Thanks. Does the `FontFamily` you create the `Font` with need to live at least as long as the `Font` does, or can it be destroyed before the `Font`? Also, I'm not using .NET version, I'm using the native C++ version.

Comment: It is only useful here to test if the font exists.  It isn't otherwise connected to the Font instance you'll create when you're happy about the family actually being available.  Windows follows the path of least resistance.  What kind of service call do you like?  Select between "the program crashed with a 'font not available' message".  Or "it doesn't look like the screen shot in your manual".  The font fallback feature in Windows ensures that something reasonable will happen in the latter case.  Unless it is a symbol font.

Comment: By the way IsAvailable() is just
    `inline BOOL Font::IsAvailable() const { return (nativeFont ? TRUE : FALSE); }`